# JQuery Divs are Multiplying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function with jQuery that will randomly place a set of 3 divs somewhere on the screen. The `.face` div, inside of which is `.left eye` div and a `.right eye` div. It fades in, fades out, removes the `$(this)`, and calls the function again. All that is working.

My current problem is I'd like to have multiple `face` classes appearing and disappearing, so I put everything into a for loop. Unfortunately, it is no longer removing the divs. So the first iteration creates 2 divs, the next iteration creates 4, then 8, and keeps doubling forever.

(I set the delay to 30000 to make it really slow. Originally the delay was shorter but this crashed the browser.)

Any idea what I've done wrong?

```
(function makeDiv(){

  for (var x=0; x<2; x++) {

  var posx = Math.floor(Math.random()*(60+1)+10);
  var posy = Math.floor(Math.random()*(60+1)+10);

  $face$x = $('<div><div class="left eye"></div><div class="right eye"></div></div>').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'%',
        'top':posy+'%',
        'display':'none'
    }).addClass( "face" ).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(30000).fadeOut(200, function(){
       $(this).remove();//

       makeDiv(); 

    });  }
}) 

();
```

[Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/adam_weiler/pen/qJKdgO)

Comment: Are "left", "right", and "eye" all different classes?  If not, I would recommend renaming the classes "left eye" and "right eye" to be "leftEye" and "rightEye".  It is defining, for example, "left" and "eye" to be two different classes.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that every call to method **makeDiv()** register 2 recursive calls to this same method (because of the loop inside). So, the first call puts on the queue two calls to this method, and every one of these two calls on the queue will create two more calls, this is the reason they are multiplying. I have made you an example of how i will do something similar to what you wants, the main idea is to create a new **face** every X milliseconds using **setInterval()**, then this new created **face** will be faded out and removed after a random delay time. Hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(event)
{
    var eye = $(".eye");
    var x = (eye.offset().left) + (eye.width() / 2);
    var y = (eye.offset().top) + (eye.height() / 2);
    var rad = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
    var rot = (rad * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
    
    eye.css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + rot + 'deg)'
    });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    createFace();
    setInterval(createFace, 5000);
});

function createFace()
{  
    var posx = Math.floor(Math.random()*(60+1)+10);
    var posy = Math.floor(Math.random()*(60+1)+10);
    var delayTime = Math.random() * 10000 + 10000;
  
    $('<div class="face"><div class="left eye"></div><div class="right eye"></div></div>')
    .css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'%',
        'top':posy+'%',
        'display':'none'
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn(100)
    .delay(delayTime)
    .fadeOut(500, function(){$(this).remove();});
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.face {
  position: relative;
  width: 7em;
  border: white 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.eye {
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 1em;

  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.eye.animate {
  transition: all 100ms;
}

.eye:after {
  content: " ";
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#animate {
  outline: none;
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid thin #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#animate:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  border: solid thin white;
}

.spookyEyes {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.arrowUp {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  //background-color: pink;
  border-left: 10em solid transparent;
  border-right: 10em solid transparent;
  
  border-bottom: 10em solid white;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="face" style="display:none;">
  <div class="left eye"></div>
  <div class="right eye"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="spooekyEyes"></div>
<div class="arreeowUp"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that, since you're calling the function multiple times (var x=0; x<2; x++), and it's recursive, you're going to end up with an overflow eventually. Meaning every time it calls itself it loops a few more times, and each time those loop those call more loops, etc.

Not quite sure what the intended outcome is, but you should just wrap the recursion in a function and call it separately for each face you want to create. You can put a setTimeout() if you want a delay in there. The below creates any number of faces and simulatenously fades them in and out, set by the 'x<5' value:

```
(function makeDiv(){

  for (var x=0; x<5; x++) {
    what();
  }

 function what() {

  var posx = Math.floor(Math.random()*(60+1)+10);
  var posy = Math.floor(Math.random()*(60+1)+10);

  $face$x = $('<div><div class="left eye"></div><div class="right eye"></div></div>').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'%',
        'top':posy+'%',
        'display':'none'
    }).addClass( "face" ).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(3000).fadeOut(200, function(){
      this.remove();
       what(); 
    }); 
  }
})();
```